# securing an asp.net web service for use with jquery ajax

Tags: asp.net, web-services, jquery, security

I'm using jquery ajax to fetch data from an asp.net webservice.  I'm wondering how I can secure it and have it work with jquery ajax.  The service is part of my web application and to access it you have to be logged in to the application.  However I'd like to further secure it.  For example a consultant looking up all their customers in an autocomplete box is good, but they can instead send in some other consultant's id.  What's the best way to secure this?
I've looked at this article here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w67h0dw7%28VS.71,classic%29.aspx .  However, I don't know how to make this work with jquery ajax.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand you want to make sure that you know the identity of the person using your service. If the web service is part of your application this should not be a problem by using cookies (assuming the web service is on the same domain as the site). See [this e-book](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=-WShG0uezvEC&pg=PA124&lpg=PA124&dq=cookie+tokens+asp.net&source=bl&ots=BxnkVurSET&sig=GIWFaw5gV0vSzd0R0hALj0J7uSs&hl=en&ei=zszdSuWIJMjB-QaJ56U3&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CBQQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=cookie%20tokens%20asp.net&f=false) for some ideas.

Otherwise you could hand out temporary identifiers to the logged in members of your site which would be used in the webservice calls - this way even if the identifier is stolen, it can only be used for a limited time.

Comment: i've been thinking a lot about this topic over the past couple of days... and I like the solution from your second paragraph very much. Thank you.

Comment: happened to revisit this. Ah to be young and inexperienced again! :p

Answer (score 1):

I made it more secure by using encryption.  I encrypt the consultant's id when passing it via ajax, and decrypt it on the server side.  Obviously I do the encryption on server side and pass it to client when rendering the page. And then ajax makes the call using that encrypted id.